# After including ui.router application stopped to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While i was using ngRoute my application was fully working, but now i have switched to [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and app doesn't work.

this is app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router', 'uiSwitch']);


app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('otherwise', {
            url : '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/todolists.html',
            controller: 'todoCtrl'
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/todolists.html',
            controller: 'todoCtrl'
        })
        .state('page', {
            url: '/:pageNumber',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/todolists.html',
            controller: 'todoCtrl'
        })
        .state('view', {
            url: '/view/:todoId',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/viewtodolist.html',
            controller: 'todoViewCtrl'
        })
        .state('add', {
            url: '/add_new',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/addtodolist.html',
            controller: 'todoAddCtrl'
        })
        .state('edit', {
            url: '/edit/:todoId',
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/edittodolist.html',
            controller: 'todoEditCtrl'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

this is my controller

```
    var app = angular.module('app');
    var controllers = {};

    controllers.todoCtrl = function ($scope, $timeout, todoFactory, $state, $stateParams) {

        console.log('test');
        if(!$stateParams.pageNumber){
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.currentPage = $stateParams.pageNumber;
        }
        console.log($scope.currentPage);
        getData();

        //get another portions of data on page chang$locationed
        $scope.pageChanged = function () {
            $state.go("details", {pageNumber: $scope.currentPage });
        };

        /**
         * Get list of todos with pagination
         */
        function getData() {
            todoFactory.index($scope.currentPage).then(function (data) {
                $scope.totalItems = data.paging.count;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = data.paging.limit;
                $scope.todos = data.Todos;
            });
        }
    };
    app.controller(controllers);
```

and this is my index.html where i load scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Angular stuff -->
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-npm/dist/angular-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap-npm/dist/angular-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-switch/angular-ui-switch.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/todoCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/factories/todoFactory.js"></script>
<script src="app/filters/dateFilter.js"></script>
```

The problem is that i don't get any errors, controller isn't loaded (otherwise test string would be printed in console), there is just blank page (check image below).
[image]

Comment: You are passing strings to controller property on the state objects. These properties are expecting functions to use as controllers. There is another property, called 'controllerAs' that allows you to set how you want to refer to the controller in the view itself.

Comment: so how exactly should my state params look like? can you make an example

Comment: You can pass Strings as controller, it finds the right controller if it is properly defined. You are defining the controllers in an object, where are you injecting this controllers into the app itself?

Comment: @yBrodsky what exactly do i need to do in controller so my states will start to work? or how to inject controllers into app itself?

Comment: angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('TodoListController', function() {}). Check the examples here https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're not assigning a name to your controller.

So try something like this

```
var app = angular.module('app');

    app.controller('TodoCtrl', TodoCtrl);

    // minification safe injection
    TodoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout', 'todoFactory', '$state', '$stateParams');

    function TodoCtrl ($scope, $timeout, todoFactory, $state, $stateParams) {

        console.log('test');
        if(!$stateParams.pageNumber){
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
        } else {
            $scope.currentPage = $stateParams.pageNumber;
        }
        console.log($scope.currentPage);
        getData();

        //get another portions of data on page chang$locationed
        $scope.pageChanged = function () {
            $state.go("details", {pageNumber: $scope.currentPage });
        };

        /**
         * Get list of todos with pagination
         */
        function getData() {
            todoFactory.index($scope.currentPage).then(function (data) {
                $scope.totalItems = data.paging.count;
                $scope.itemsPerPage = data.paging.limit;
                $scope.todos = data.Todos;
            });
        }
    };
```

In addition to that I highly recommend to read [John Papas Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) 
It will teach you things like avoiding $scope and using the controllerAs syntax